# xslt dropdown problems

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a page with two drop down boxes created in a xslt.

I am using onchange in both blocks to call a javascript function. If both drop downs are loaded on the page only the first drop down has a working onchange.

I checked the view source code and it shows both onchange events.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

ex: two drop downs, select first one, it refreshes, select second it does nothing, select first one and it still refreshes.

code removed.

Comment: XSLT is irrelevant here. It's an HTML/JS issue. Just post your "view source" output.

Comment: This was due to me using the wrong checks in my javascript code, it was not hitting any of my functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should put in a

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

declaration into your XSLT. The interspersed XML declaration should not be in the HTML.

The HTML you show does not exhibit any other immediate problems (apart from UPPERCASE tag names *shudder*). If there is a problem, then it is a browser subtlety (some browsers don't fire the change event until the focus leaves the form field) or a JavaScript problem in `submitForm();`.